# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_mysql.so

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, php-7.1

After an updrade of Ubuntu where php7.3 has been installed I can not load the mysql library when I execute php7.1. So, when I execute `php7.1 -v` I get this message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator in Unknown on line 0
```

However, when I execute `php7.3 -v` it's all right.

I've tried to install `apt-get install php-mysql` to reinstall it, but it doesn't work. I have tried `apt-get install php7.1-mysql` but appearently it doesn't exist.

I've also tried to copy and to create symbolinc links to pdo_mysql.so that php7.3 is using but it neither works.